# ARKit sometimes crash when "runWithConfiguration" does on iPhone6s, 6sPlus

Tags: ios, ios11, arkit

I'm working with ARKit. Sometimes, I get a crash when arsession run With Configration on iPhone6s, 6sPlus.
Only these devices are crashing, maybe its' only for Apple A9 Chip..

The incidence is not high. If you have this experience, In such cases, I seek help with how to defend the code.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureDevice setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:] Unsupported frame duration - use -activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges to discover valid ranges'

```
0   CoreFoundation  0x000000018403f164 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation) + 124
1   libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000183288528 objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib) + 56
2   AVFoundation    0x000000018998d368 __58-[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:]_block_invoke (in AVFoundation) + 540
3   libdispatch.dylib   0x00000001839bea14 _dispatch_client_callout (in libdispatch.dylib) + 16
4   libdispatch.dylib   0x00000001839c7618 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete (in libdispatch.dylib) +     56
5   AVFoundation    0x000000018998d070 -[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:] (in AVFoundation) + 184
6   ARKit   0x000000019ec562e0 -[ARImageSensor configureCaptureDevice] (in ARKit) + 260
7   ARKit   0x000000019ec54c80 -[ARImageSensor start] (in ARKit) + 440
8   ARKit   0x000000019ec61b88 -[ARSession _startSensorsWithDataTypes:] (in ARKit) + 1452
9   ARKit   0x000000019ec5da28 -[ARSession _updateSessionWithConfiguration:options:] (in ARKit) + 1296
10  ARKit   0x000000019ec5bf48 __42-[ARSession runWithConfiguration:options:]_block_invoke (in ARKit) + 164
11  libdispatch.dylib   0x00000001839bea54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release (in libdispatch.dylib) + 24
```